# XMPPHP with facebook access token

Tags: php, facebook, xmpp, token, xmpphp

How can I log to XMPP with Facebook access token instead of user's password?
Is there any way? I read STH about SIG, but I don't know how it really looks like.
I tried replace password with access token, doesn't work.

My code:

```
$conn = new XMPPHP_XMPP('chat.facebook.com', 5222,  $_POST['usr'], $p, 'xmpphp',               'chat.facebook.com', $printlog=true, $loglevel=XMPPHP_Log::LEVEL_DEBUG);
```

And I have to replace $p (password) with access token or STH, when I'm logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several hours of researching and coding, I finally got it!

1) Download XMPPHP Library

2) Overwrite these 3 files - http://codejaw.com/2g73va7

**Attention:** This is a hack I made myself. So that XMPPHP version will only work with Facebook and only with Access Token. This will no longer work with others services or Facebook passwords.

Maybe some coder will use my work and make a full (non-hacked) version.

Enjoy!